# Android compare to a time to current time continuously

Tags: android, timer, alarm

I am making an app which need to compare two date and time continuously.
I just saw some example which just compare once. I think I can use timer to repeat a method but it seem not very efficient. Anyone did this before?

Comment: You could try using an AsyncTask in order to compare the two times at a certain interval.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: use ScheduledExecutorService

Comment: I am not making an alarm app. It just show something to the user after the time user set. So ScheduledExecutorService seems not appropriate.

Comment: I am trying using while loop in AsyncTask, but i am afraid it waste a lot memory when user set a lot things it need compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use `postDelayed` like below.

```
Handler handler = new Handler(); 
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override 
    public void run() { 
        compareTime();
    } 
}, 5000);
```

replace 5000 with your own interval milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you! It seems easiest way to make it.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy, you can use handler; When the first time to check time send the normal message like this

```
 mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(CHECK_TIME);
```

Afterwards sendDelayedMessage from inside the handler.

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler() {

    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case CHECK_TIME:
            // Your compare time code here
            // ....
            // Send the delayed message to handler to check time again
            mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(mHandler.obtainMessage(CHECK_TIME),
                DELAY_CHECK_TIME_INTERVAL); 
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It make sense. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, If it is working. please accept answer and up vote.